# CoffeeScript doesn't work onclick

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

CoffeScript code:

```
 department = ->
   console.log 1
```

This compiles into js code :

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var department;

  department = function() {
    return console.log(1);
  };

}).call(this);
```

And I have a button :

```
<button onclick = "department()" >add department</button>
```

But when I click it it throws an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: department is not defined

So what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because your function `department` is not in the global scope, instead it is in a closure of your anonymous function that you have written as IIFE.

`<button onclick = "department()" >add department</button>` when clicked will look for the function `department()` in the global scope and you don't have it there.

This is what happens when you have handlers written as inline html attributes. You can bind the event using javascript giving the function as reference within your closure.

You could do:

Example:-

```
 <button id="dept"  >add department</button>
```

and

```
(function() {
  var department;

  department = function() {
    return console.log(1);
  };

  window.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById('dept').onclick = department;
  }

}).call(this);
```

Comment: That answers why but doesn't answer how should i change my cofeescript code to make it work

Comment: @user2950593 I don't know about coffee script syntax but you can check one i provided.

Comment: But there should be the way to add it just via Html in coffee script.. I got ur idea. I just think it's a little bit weird that it can't be done in html.

Comment: You could try placing it out of the closure so that it is in global scope.. or `(function() {

  window.department = function() {
    return console.log(1);
  };

}).call(this);
` However you should get rid of binding the events inline html, instead you should bind them via js, using `addEventListener`, `attachEvent`(for older IEs) etc..

Comment: @user2950593 Why did you unaccept my answer? I said `You could try placing it out of the closure so that it is in global scope` so it means obviously to put it in global scoperight. you can easily do it using http://js2coffee.org/ But i provided a much efficient and better alternative options..

Comment: @user2950593 Thanks so quick. I didn't know what was wrong with mine. What i meant wasy instead of doing inline handlers you should register it with register it with JS, you can google about it or SO about it.

Comment: It was about 5 am in the morning for me:D

Answer (score 1):

```
window.department = ->
    console.log 1
```

`window` before any coffeescript function will make it global

also

```
@window.department = ->
    console.log 1
```

the `@` symbol refers to `this` which in this case refers to the `document`.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but if anyone happens to stumble upon this like I did...

Simply add `--bare` as an argument when compiling to not wrap the code in an anonymous function.

Then instead of calling CoffeeScript directly, we just use the compiled js file, like if you wrote it in JS yourself.

```html
<button onclick="getCoffee()">From CoffeeScript</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/getcoffee.js"></script>
```

Don't need anything special in your CoffeeScript this way.

```coffee
getCoffee = () ->
  alert "Delicious Coffee..."
```

Comment: really old post have no idea if ur solution works